# Cron and background operand &

Tags: unix, background, cron

Is it incorrect that if you schedule a job with Cron and include the `background operand &`? For example:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/prstat -Z -n 0 -c 60 1440 > /var/log/avgload/test.txt &
```

**Edit**: 
Another question. I try to schedule the job one time at the reboot - @reboot - but the SmartOS would not take it, what is alternative? For example

```
@reboot /usr/bin/prstat -Z -n 0 -c 60 > /var/log/avgload/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from 'man sh':
    "If  a  command  is terminated by the control operator &,
    the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.
    The shell does  not wait  for  the command to finish, and the return status is 0."

The cron daemon recognizes exit codes of every started cron job and can write it to a log file (assuming a properly machine configuration).

An excerpt from a cron daemon log file on Solaris:

```
 >  CMD:  /path/cronjob ...
 >  user pid c Sun Apr 24 10:00:00 2014                           
 ..............................................
 <  user pid c Sun Apr 24 10:12:33 2014 rc=127
```

A notation of finish time of each cron job together with possible not 0 return code is the only information about success and duration of each cron job from the cron daemon. Such information is required for cron job maintenance and monitoring.

If you want to hide such free of charge information intentionally, you can use the '&'.
There is no sense to use '&' in cron tables, at least at the last position of cron jobs.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I have another question of the same subject.